# Why don't Youtube comments fire a DOM mutation?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension. Its content script should fire every time the page it's on changes, and it does most of the times. I'm using a `MutationObserver` for this.

However, when I'm on Youtube (and possibly other websites in which I haven't noticed the problem) and I scroll down to load the comments, the `MutationObserver` doesn't fire. Why is this, shouldn't the DOM have changed?

EDIT: I might want to add that I set the observer to monitor changes in the `subtree`, `childList` and `attribute` of `document.body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube comments are loaded in an iframe. If you want to watch for mutations of YouTube comments you have to set your content script to be `"all_frames": true` in the manifest and add the iframe URL pattern to match against.

Comment: Oh! That's where the catch was. Thanks a lot for helping me out, as I'm still new to this world as you may have noticed.